# phaser on vscode launch

Tags: visual-studio-code, phaser-framework

I've created a simple game using Phaser on vscode.
I read that i need to run it locally in order to run it on chrome and i can't manage to do so using vscode's F5.

when im on "index.html" and pressing F5 it pops out an alert box that says "cannot find progrem to debug".
pressing F5 while im on any other file causes a error in the debugger "window is not defined"(when im on phanser.js)/"Phaser is not defined"(when im on any other file)

how can i start this program correctlly ? sorry for the basic question .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http-server works just fine. But if you want to debug the game easily. You might want to follow the steps in this post: https://divillysausages.com/2015/06/09/using-phaser-with-visual-studio-code/

It is an instruction for setting up Typescript phaser development in vscode, but the steps that teach you how to set up node server also applies to a javascript usage case. If you want to make it easy to debug(pause code executing while game running, etc.) Try to set it up in that way.

Answer (score 0):

Had to install http-server from npm and run it in terminal.

tried it before, but accidently installed it not globaly.
now it works. thanks!